# change django from python2.6 to python2.7

Tags: python, django, linux, ubuntu

I am new Linux (Ubuntu) and Python,my Ubuntu come with  python2.6.6 installed in it. I newly install python 2.7, and then installed django.

I want to configure django with python2.7. But now it configured with python2.6. I am totally confused since I am new to Linux/Python.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use virtualenvwrapper. To install:

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

and then modify your .bashrc as described in http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper/

To use:

```
mkvirtualenv ENV_NAME --python=python2.7 --no-site-packages
workon ENV_NAME
pip install whatever packages you need
# or
pip install -r requirement_file.txt
```

each time you are in you env, the python is 2.7